# Wired and Wireless connection on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

When LAN is connected, Wifi is not operational. This causes me to not have internet in my particular case.

I've got a linux device that I connect to via ethernet. This requires a static IP on the same subnet. The device does not provide internet. I do not intend to ever connect to the internet over LAN with this computer.

This used to work fine under windows 7, but now doesn't work at Windows 10.

I know there are multiple other questions similar to this, but I haven't been helped by them.

Here is what I've tried:

1. I've checked my BIOS. This is an HP laptop, and they do have a bios setting to switch off wlan when lan makes a connection as a power setting. This is off.
2. Turned off in the wifi adapter configuration the option to allow the OS to turn off the adapter to save power.
3. Under the Wifi ip4 Advanced settings, setting a metric lower than the LAN adapter. (the most common suggestion)
4. Under Group Settings for the computer, disabled the "Minimize the number of simultaneous connections" policy.
5. I've tried making sure the LAN ip4 settings do not set a default gateway.
6. Looked for another setting under ip4 configuration regarding disabled when LAN is connected. This doesn't exist for me.

Under Network Properties, it displays that the wifi is "Not Operational" but appears to still have a connection.

I'm hoping there is some other setting I'm missing regarding wifi being disabled when LAN is connected because that seems to be the behavior.

**EDIT**
Adding ipconfig /all output with some stuff hidden by me per requested in comments:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : {MyHost}
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : {MyDomain}.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : {MyDomain}.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Physical Address 1}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : {MyStaticIP}
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Physical Address 2}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Physical Address 3}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : {mydomain}.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Physical Address 4}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: While there are ways to enable a LAN networking adapter and a wireless adapter at the same time, the default behavior, is to only connect to one of those adapters at a time.  This also isn't something new in Windows 10.  Only using one of those adapters has always been the case (you might have made the required changes when you used Windows 7).

Comment: This is not a behavior of Windows 10. From a priority stand point, all things equal, Windows will prefer the highest speed connection but multiple connections are perfectly supported and usable by default. I immediately thought about the BIOS setting you suggested. If it’s off, that is strange. What is the output of `ipconfig /all` when both networks are connected?

Comment: Edited the original post with that info. I'm not sure what I'm looking at with this.

Comment: Ramhound, could be, it's been 2 years.

Comment: This is normal behavior in Win10 @Appleoddity. I suppose it may be driver-dependent, but the option to disable wireless, or not connect to wireless networks when the wired connection is connected is built-in to the OS.

Comment: music2myear, I don't doubt it from the settings I saw in the Group Settings. But is there something I've missed in Win10 settings?